# Node Express function gets executed twice

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I have a route defined in my `server.js` file like:

```
app.use('/file', require('./server/routes/file.js'));
```

On the top of the `file.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var outsideHelper = require('./outsideHelper');
 ...

router.post('/file', async function(req, res, next){
  //Code
   var connection = await dbFunc.dbConnect(sqlPool);
   var result = await outsideHelper.DoStuff(res, connection);
})

module.exports = router;
```

`outsideHelper` works fine, and is exported in that file via

```
module.exports = {
  DoStuff: async function(res, connection){
    try {
      var localSiteRes = await localFileFunction(res, connection);
      return localSiteRes;
    }catch(err){
      return false;
    }

  }
```

The network only shows one request to the `file.js` however when `outsideHelper.DoStuff` function is used inside this request `router.post('/file...` the request gets ran twice, server side. When I remove the outsideHelper function from this however, it only runs once.

Everything works just fine, except on the first attempt after starting my local server.

- I do not have a route defined for `outsideHelper.js` in my `server.js` because it is not an externally called route, it gets required within the `file.js` file.
- `localFileFunction` uses JSFTP

Still kinda new to node.js and express.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly gets run twice?  Can you show more code so we can see a greater context?

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of the issue, but I don't believe that `express` routes accept `async` functions... though to be fair, I've never tried, either.

Comment: @jfriend00, The entire route router.post('/file', async function(req, res, next){ gets executed twice, however the network only fires once.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, I use async with many routes, they work just fine.

Comment: @GrantWeiss interesting... looks like I have some awesome updates to make to some of my projects for... readability improvement.

Comment: But yeah, if that's the case, then I'm with @jfriend00 you need to share more code to figure out what's going on. Currently this question does not follow the [mcve] guideline on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Apparently then you are somehow registering the route handler more than once.  We need to see more code to help you find that.

Comment: @GrantWeiss I realize you think you're sharing enough information, but like I said, this problem is still not verifiable. And by that, I mean we can't reproduce the suspect behavior you're describing just based off this code.